# Identify Selected CheckBoxes in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-checkbox

I have created a `ListView` with a `Checkbox` and some `TextView`s as attached in below. I have created a `Android Activity` and `extends` it from `ListActivity`. I'm using a `SimpleAdapter` to fill my `ListView` with below code in my `Android Activity`. Data retrieving from a database to fill this `ListView`.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
        saleDriver.getOutstandings(clientId),
        R.layout.outstanding_list_row, new String[] {
                "sale_date", "invoice_number", "sale_total", },
        new int[] { R.id.tt_invoice_date,
                R.id.tt_invoice_no, R.id.tt_invoice_tot });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Also display a button (assume `Pay`) when user press `Menu` button in android device. When user checked one or more `CheckBoxes` and press that button, i need to obtain data in that list rows. (according to example image attached in below, i need to get `4341` and `0910201`).

how could i do this ?

[image: Android ListView with CheckBox]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the state of the checkboxes checked with the row number when the user hits the menu button you can use these rows and get the required data. I would suggest to use a custom adapter to have a lot more control over the data.

Comment: can you please provide some example.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html this is what you need to go through to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
       }
      }
```

See the [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) below, it may help you, In this page go below to see the custom listview with checkbox and it's listener.It may be what you need.